# Returning a specific course using sqlite 3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am having trouble returning a specific course with their own respective instructor and section when entering my code...

```
def run_query(db, q, args=None):
"""(str, str, tuple) -> list of tuple
Return the results of running query q with arguments args on
database db."""

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()
# execute the query with the given args passed
# if args is None, we have only a query
if args is None:
    cur.execute(q)
else:
    cur.execute(q, args)

results = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
return results




def get_course_instructors(db, course):
    '''Return the Course number, sections and instructors for the given course number.'''

    return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Course, Sections, Name FROM Courses 
    WHERE Course = "course" ''')

`get_course_instructors(db,'AFSA01H3F')
[('ACTB40H3F', 'LEC01', 'S. Damouras\n'), ('AFSA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'S. Rockel\n'), ('AFSB51H3F', 'LEC01', 'H. Dinani\n')
```

`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show `run_query`.

Comment: @CL I did, thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, words without quotes or in double quotes are table/column names. Anything in single quotes is a string.

So `Course = "course"` means to match any row where the value in the `Course` column is equal with itself.

To get values from Python into SQL, you should use [SQL parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```
run_query(db,
          ''' SELECT Course, Sections, Name
              FROM Courses 
              WHERE Course = ? ''',
          [course])
```

Comment: @ CL. thank you very much, especially sharing the SQL parameters link. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Just to confirm, your db variable is your cursor, right? Usually your db initialization would resemble something like this:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("courses.db")
c = connection.cursor()
```

And then you would use `c` to refer to the db. Leaving your parameters as-is, your solution might look something like this:

```
def get_course_instructors(db, course_num):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT course_num, section, instructor FROM courses WHERE course_num = '{}'".format(course_num)
        db.execute(sql)
        result = db.fetchall()
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Of course, you should check your result at some point to ensure that you actually got one, either in this function or the one calling it.

Comment: @ Joseph I inserted my run_query function and my connection is conn = sqlite3.connect(db)